# Populate custom component with store

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, store

Im trying to populate a custom component using a store (actually a store with local data) in a Sencha Touch 2 project.

My idea is to create one custom component for each element in the store, but actually nothing happens.

I have tried several things but anything works, could you help me? I have done an example to show the problem:

**model:**

```
Ext.define('project.model.city', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  config: {
    fields: [
      {name: 'country', type: 'string'},
      {name: 'city', type: 'string'}
    ]
  }
});
```

**store:**

```
Ext.define('project.store.cities', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
  requires: ['project.model.city'],
  model: 'project.model.city',
  autoLoad: true,
  data: [
    { country: 'Germany', city: 'Berlin' },
    { country: 'Italy', city: 'Rome' }
  ]
});
```

**View with store:**

```
Ext.define('project.view.cityAll', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'cityAllView',
  config: {
    items:[{
      xtype: 'cityItemView',
      store: 'project.store.cities',
    }]
  }
});
```

**Custom component View:**

```
Ext.define('project.view.cityItem', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'cityItemView',
  config: {
    items: [{
      itemTpl: '{city}'
    }]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign store to cityItemView instead of cityAllView. `cityItemView` is having template specified and needs to be loaded with data.

```
Ext.define('project.view.cityItem', {
  extend: 'Ext.Panel',
  xtype: 'cityItemView',
  config: {
    items: [{
      xtype:'list', 
      itemTpl: '{city}'
      store:'project.store.cities'
    }]
  }
});
```

If you want to set data into panel, then you'd need to call `setData()`. A panel can not load data from store directly. You can use list view instead so show city, country pair. cityView no longer needed store property that way.

Give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can add load listener in store which would loop through records and create as many panels:

```
    listeners : {
        load: function( me, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){ 
            var plist = [];
            var cv = Ext.Create('project.view.cityAll');
            if(successful){

                var data = records[i].getData();
                for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++){
                    plist.push({
                        xtype : 'cityItemView',
                        data : data
                    });
                }
                cv.add(plist);
            } 
            // Now add cv to viewport or wherever you want
        }
}
```

You have to change `cityItemView` to use data whichever way you want. If you are using initialize method you can access it like `this.config.data`